# Regular expression for detect [something],162,1);

Tags: regex, notepad, regular-language

Hello I want to replace some strings using notepad, I have to search something like:

```
4.13723725115740744492e+04,162,1);
```

I mean:

```
[something],162,1);
```

And replace by:

```
'2015-04-02 10:46:28',162,1);
```

Comment: A rather easy task with regex. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Find what:**

```
[^,]+(?=,162,1\);)
```

`(?=,162,1\);)` a positive lookahead assertion which asserts that the match must be followed by `,162,1);`.

**Replace with:**

```
'2015-04-02 10:46:28'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zY2sZ5/1)